# How to regenerate Resource.designer.cs file Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

So I am new to Xamarin studio and have been stuck on a little bit of a frustrating issue.  Every time I make a change within the resources file, the Resource.designer.cs file does not regenerate and recognize the new changes.  Does anyone know how I can update the changes so that I can interact with newly added widgets?  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Android's .csproj file and make sure the following `AndroidResgenXXXX` properties are included within a `PropertyGroup` (within the `Project`)

```
<AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
<AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
```

Comment: I do not see a .csproj file in my file tree.  I see an `AndroidManifest.xml` file and an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file listed under the folder `Properties`

Comment: @hermt2 `.csproj` is the file extension of `CSharp Project` files, your Solution (`.sln`) will contain one or more `XXXXXX.csproj` files : If you are using Xamarin Studio, just right-click on the Android project and select edit, if using Visual Studio :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171487(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I found the `.csproj` file in my finder, and I am using Xamarin Studio.  I'm not sure exactly where the Android project file is that you arfe speaking of.  I've right clicked several different folders and files in my project file tree and none of them give me an edit option. I have also tried to open up the `.csproj` file in my finder but all it does is reopen the same project.

Comment: It is your Android project, not any file within that project, but the project itself. Highlight your android project, right-click, goto `Tools` and select `Edit File`

Comment: I saw then Android option but it was not enabled to click.  I opened the document in another text editor and added those lines into a <PropertyGroup> tag.  The project is taking a while to rebuild I will let you know if it succeeds.

Comment: @hermt2 Glad to hear it, happy Xammie coding ;-)